# gap above the first box when trying to align two boxes in sequence using display: inline-block;

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make those boxes sit next to each other, but for some reason, it creates a huge gap above the blue box.

Also, how would you remove the gap between the blue and the green box?

Thank you in advance :)

```css
body,
header,
h1,
div {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height:100px;
  background-color: red;
}

h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}

div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <h1>text</h1>
    <div></div>
  </header>
</body>
```

Comment: just remove `display: inline` from every where and add `display:flex` in css for header. 
It will work as you want.
Its the efficient and effective way of down sizing your code with the same features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `vertical-align: middle;` to `h1` and `div`. I used float to remove the gap between the blue and the green box.

```css
body,
header,
h1,
div {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  vertical-align: middle;
  float: left;
}

div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
  vertical-align: middle;
  clear:left;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>text</h1>
  <div></div>
</header>
```

Also you can use flex for header

```css
body,
header,
h1,
div {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  display:flex;
}

h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}

div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>text</h1>
  <div></div>
</header>
```